# Selenium Script working in Chrome but unable to enter login credential from IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

`Selenium Script` working in `Chrome` but unable to enter login credential from IE
Getting error as `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page to load`.

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.141.59.0
Listening on port 1948
Only local connections are allowed
Sep 19, 2020 10:41:37 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
hmmmmm1
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page to load.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-M037PSRF', ip: '193.168.10.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:1948/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c25bb510-26ed-45d3-9668-0a9e1fa699ea
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at Com.SB.NewBusiness.CoreIESelf.main(CoreIESelf.java:36)
```

Comment: post also the code snippet

Comment: update you implicit wait or use explicit time to wait for page loading

Comment: @AnkitaRai Where can I find _...hmmmmm1..._?